# MySQL Query using sub query twice

Tags: mysql

I have this query

```
SELECT itemID, locationParentID, locationID, categoryParentID, categoryID, itemTitle, itemDetails, itemAttributes, itemPictures, itemFeatured, itemSpotlight, itemAdded 
FROM items 
WHERE locationID NOT IN
    (SELECT locationID 
    FROM sites_locations 
    WHERE siteID != 2) AND items.siteID IN('1,2') AND itemStatus = '1' 
    AND itemAdded > '1356048000'
```

and it works fine but when I perform this query it fails

```
SELECT itemID, locationParentID, locationID, categoryParentID, categoryID, 
itemTitle, itemDetails, itemAttributes, itemPictures, itemFeatured, itemSpotlight, itemAdded FROM items 
WHERE locationID NOT IN
    (SELECT locationID 
     FROM sites_locations WHERE siteID != 2) 
     AND categoryID NOT IN (SELECT categoryID FROM sites_categories 
     WHERE siteID != 2) AND items.siteID IN('1,2') AND itemStatus = '1' 
     AND itemAdded > '1356048000'
```

the difference here is I have added the clause

```
AND categoryID NOT IN(SELECT categoryID FROM sites_categories 
WHERE siteID != ".$cfg['site']['siteID'].")
```

any ideas why this would not work?

or even better, a Join Query to help optimize it.

table structure for sites_categories, data is in
[image]

table structure for items, data is in
[image]

table structure for sites_locations
[image]

table structure for locations, data is in
[image]

thanks in advance.

Comment: can you replace the not in by inner join]

Comment: The query is not working when I add the second sub query, I do not want the site using siteID = '2' to beable to query items which it does not have in the table sites_categories, thanks

Comment: $20 to the first person that gets it to work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT i.itemID, i.locationParentID, i.locationID, i.categoryParentID, i.categoryID, 
i.itemTitle, i.itemDetails, i.itemAttributes, i.itemPictures, i.itemFeatured, i.itemSpotlight, i.itemAdded 
FROM    items i,  sites_locations sl, sites_categories sc  
WHERE i.locationID = sl.locationID 
AND i.categoryID = sc.categoryID   
AND i.siteID = 1 AND i.itemStatus = '1' 
AND i.itemAdded > '1356048000'
```

It may have some error or column name related error pl correct those error

Comment: @IanWilkinson You saved your $20 ;) :P

Answer (score 0):

You can turn it into joins like thus:

```
SELECT i.itemID, i.locationParentID, i.locationID, i.categoryParentID, i.categoryID, 
       i.itemTitle, i.itemDetails, i.itemAttributes, i.itemPictures, i.itemFeatured,
       i.itemSpotlight, i.itemAdded
FROM items i left outer join
     sites_locations sl
     on i.locationID = sl.locationId and sl.siteId <> 2 left outer join
     sites_categories sc
     on i.categoryID = sc.categoryId and sc.siteId <> 2
WHERE sl.locationID is NULL and sc.categoryId is NULL and
      i.siteID IN (1, 2) AND i.itemStatus = 1 AND i.itemAdded > 1356048000
```

This may also have better performance.

Note:  I haven't tested this SQL so it might have syntax errors.  In particular, you may need to add aliases before some of the column names (it is good practice to always use aliases before column names).

Comment: Nope, still not working, I will have a mess with it and see if I can get it going, if I do get it working with your code I am a man of my word and $20 will be heading you way :)

Comment: Solved  SELECT itemID, locationParentID, locationID, categoryParentID, categoryID, itemTitle, itemDetails, itemAttributes, itemPictures, itemFeatured, itemSpotlight, itemAdded FROM items WHERE items.siteID IN('1,2') AND items.locationID = (SELECT locationID FROM sites_locations sl WHERE sl.locationID = items.locationID AND siteID = '2') AND items.categoryID = (SELECT categoryID FROM sites_categories sc WHERE sc.categoryID = items.categoryID AND siteID = '2') AND itemStatus = '1' AND itemAdded > '1356048000' ORDER BY itemID DESC LIMIT 15

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
SELECT itemID, locationParentID, locationID, categoryParentID, categoryID, itemTitle, itemDetails, itemAttributes, itemPictures, itemFeatured, itemSpotlight, itemAdded FROM items WHERE items.siteID IN('1,2') AND items.locationID = (SELECT locationID FROM sites_locations sl WHERE sl.locationID = items.locationID AND siteID = '2') AND items.categoryID = (SELECT categoryID FROM sites_categories sc WHERE sc.categoryID = items.categoryID AND siteID = '2') AND itemStatus = '1' AND itemAdded > '1356048000' ORDER BY itemID DESC LIMIT 15
```